# PHP PDO hangs once assigned to a variable

Tags: php, pdo, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have an internal website where we are using PHP 7.2 and connecting to multiple databases using PDO.
One database to connect to is Snowflake, for which we use its PDO driver (see https://github.com/snowflakedb/pdo_snowflake) and connect through our web proxy.

So far so good.

BUT, as soon as the PDO object gets assigned to a new variable (whether as value or reference), the execution halts - for 5 mins - before continuing.
See examples below:

FAST: No reassignment of the PDO object:

```
putenv("http_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");
putenv("https_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");

$pdo = new PDO("snowflake:account=myacount;", "myuser", "mypassword");
print(gettype($pdo));
>> it prints: 'object'
```

HANGS: PDO object is re-assigned (it hangs for about 5 mins before eventually continuing):

```
putenv("http_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");
putenv("https_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");

$pdo = new PDO("snowflake:account=myacount;", "myuser", "mypassword");
$d = $pdo;  // <= THIS LINE WAS ADDED
print(gettype($pdo));
>> it eventually prints: 'object'
```

HANGS: PDO object is re-assigned as reference (it hangs for about 5 mins before eventually continuing):

```
putenv("http_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");
putenv("https_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");

$pdo = new PDO("snowflake:account=myacount;", "myuser", "mypassword");
$d = &$pdo;  // <= THIS LINE WAS ADDED
print(gettype($pdo));
>> it eventually prints: 'object'
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe. PHP should probably optimize this internally and plain assignment would not do anything in particular. Bear in mind that assigning an object to a variable is merely giving that object another label. It's nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: @Dharman, I agree, I too have a hard time of believing what I am seeing. We do have other PDO objects which we assign around with no problem (although those don't require the proxy env variable). I too fail to see any explanation why assignment by value and especially assignment by reference should cause this, but it does. Whether or not it has to do anything with PDO, I am not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that the assignment is the reason? Maybe it is only a coincidence?

Comment: @Dharman, the only difference between scenario #1 and #2 or #3 is the assignment. When there is no assignment then there is no "hanging".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why, but adding an additional statement at the end of the script to empty out the `$pdo` variable solves the issue

THIS IS NOW FAST:

```
putenv("http_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");
putenv("https_proxy=http://ourproxy:80");

$pdo = new PDO("snowflake:account=myacount;", "myuser", "mypassword");
$d = $pdo;
print(gettype($pdo));
$pdo = null;  // <- this line was added
>> it prints: 'object'
```

The idea came from looking at the documentation of the Snowflake PDO (see https://github.com/snowflakedb/pdo_snowflake#query) where I saw that they were "nulling" the PDO object at the end of the script. I didn't think that it will make a difference, but it did.

Also the PDO documentation suggest the closing out this way, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

I am still not sure why if this last line is missing then it ONLY hangs if there was a reassignment of the PDO object, not otherwise, but oh well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am surprised that it hangs and does not error.

Comment: This makes no sense. How can doing something *after* `print()` get rid of a delay *before* `print()`? Am I misunderstanding when the delay happens?

Comment: @Barmar, I write it up to the mysteries of the PDO implementation. Maybe without proper closure of the PDO connection the PHP script does not exit - without which there is no printing either (except if there would be a manual flush added after the print).

Comment: Didn't think about output buffering. Put `flush()` after `print(gettype($pdo))`;